# NBA Player with Retired Jersey Number in Multiple Teams

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba

Has there been an NBA player who has had the jersey number retired in multiple Teams/Franchises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [official list](http://www.nba.com/multiple_jerseys_retired_071201.html) of the player with multiple jersey retired:

- Wilt Chamberlain -- #13 (Sixers/Warriors/Lakers)
- Oscar Robertson -- #1 (Bucks) #14 (Kings via Cincinnati Royals)
- Kareem Abdul-Jabbar -- #33 (Bucks/Lakers)
- Pete Maravich - #7 (Jazz/Hornets)
- Julius Erving -- #32 (Nets) #6 (Sixers)
- Earl Monroe -- #15 (Knicks) #10 (Bullets/Wizards)
- Charles Barkley -- #34 (Sixers/Suns)
- Michael Jordan – #23 (Bulls/Heat)
- Nate Thurmond -- #42 (Cavs/Warriors)
- Bob Lanier -- #16 (Pistons/Bucks)
- Clyde Drexler -- #22 (Blazers/Rockets)